# Accumulating data from previous year

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having trouble with finding a solution for below SQL-query. My first query should and does the trick of accumulating amount of last year's data.

```
CASE
WHEN rehuv.VER_DATUM >= dateadd(year, -1, dateadd(month, -datepart(month, @STARTDATE) + 1, @STARTDATE))
                                 AND rehuv.VER_DATUM <= DATEADD(year, -1, @ENDDATE) THEN rehuv.BELOPP ELSE 0 
END AS PREVIOUS_YEAR_ACC
```

But when I try to accumulate data within a specific time interval (I want the same time interval as @startdate -> @enddate but one year backwards). Sql-query:

```
CASE
WHEN rehuv.VER_DATUM >= DATEADD(year, -1, @STARTDATE)
                                 AND rehuv.VER_DATUM <= DATEADD(year, -1, @ENDDATE) THEN rehuv.BELOPP ELSE 0 
END AS PREVIOUS_YEAR_MONTH
```

Thank you in advance!

Best regards,
Simon

Comment: Which dbms product are you using? (Some non-ANSI SQL there...)

Comment: What are the values of your variables, `@startdate` and `@enddate`?

Comment: @jarlh Microsoft SQL!

Comment: @the_pete DateTime YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: @the_pete so for an example I choose startdate: 2015-01-01 and enddate: 2015-05-01. The PREVIOUS_YEAR_ACC should be the whole year 2014 and the PREVIOUS_YEAR_MONTH should be 2014-01-01 to 2015-05-01

Answer (score 0):

If you want the monthly sum of last year, you can try this:

```
DECLARE @STARTDATE DATETIME;
DECLARE @ENDDATE DATETIME;
SET @STARTDATE='2015-1-1';
SET @ENDDATE='2015-5-1';
DECLARE @LAST_YEAR DATE;
SET @LAST_YEAR = DATEADD(YEAR, -1, DATEADD(DAY, 
    DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR, GETDATE())*-1+1, CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())));

SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, DATEPART(MONTH, VER_DATUM), @LAST_YEAR) MONTH,   SUM(CASE
WHEN REHUV.VER_DATUM >= DATEADD(YEAR, -1, @STARTDATE)
AND REHUV.VER_DATUM <= DATEADD(YEAR, -1, @ENDDATE) 
THEN REHUV.BELOPP ELSE 0 
END ) AS PREVIOUS_YEAR_MONTH
FROM REHUV
GROUP BY DATEPART(MONTH, VER_DATUM)
```